# C99 variables declaration position where it is written

Tags: c, c99

I know C99 allows declarations to be mixed with code and not only at the beginning, but I'm trying to find where in  ISO/IEC 9899:1999 it is written - could you point me to the section(s) I should search?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The change is mentioned in the (non-normative) Forward, page xii, as "mixed declarations and code". (IMHO, declarations *are* "code"; it should have said "mixed declarations and statements".)

It's defined in the grammar for a *compound-statement* in 6.8.2:

```
compound-statement:
    { block-item-list[opt] }
block-item-list:
    block-item
    block-item-list block-item
block-item:
    declaration
    statement
```

The corresponding grammar in the C89/C90 standard was:

```
compound-statement:
    { declaration-list[opt] statement-list[opt] }
declaration-list:
    declaration
    declaration-list declaration
statement-list:
    statement
    statement-list statement
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in clause 6.8.2:

```
block-item: declaration
            statement
```

A `block-item` can be either a statement or a declaration, without them needing to be in a particular order:

```
compound-statement:
                    { block-item-list_opt }
block-item-list: block-item
                 block-item-list block-item
```

Answer (score 2):

C 1999 6.8.2 two says a compound-statement is “{”, an optional block-item-list, and a “}”, and that a block-item-list is either a block =-item or another block-item-list and a block-item, and that a block-item is a declaration or a statement. Therefore, a declaration can be any of the block-items in a compound-statement. In turn, 6.8 says a compound-statement can appear anywhere a statement can appear. Additionally, 6.9.1 says the body of a function-definition is a compound-statement.

```
compound-statement:
    { block-item-list[opt] }

block-item-list:
    block-item
    block-item-list block-item

block-item:
    declaration
    statement
```